# Python Dill/Pickle - No Module

Tags: python, tensorflow, pickle, dill

Alright folks,

Here is the problem I'm struggling with.

1. I have a team who produces machine learning models using tensorflow; they do not know or care much about our website.
2. I have a web team which takes the output of the ML team and operationalizes it as apis.  They need to accept just some random files and make it work.

So we decided to try pickling (or dilling) our model classes and then loading them and restoring the variable weights into them; great this works.

What doesn't work is when we ship the model definition class to the server and try to load it with dill or pickle we get the following error:

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/dill/dill.py", line 423, in find_class
    return StockUnpickler.find_class(self, module, name)
ImportError: No module named 'RANDOM_MODEL_CLASS_NAME'

This tells me that pickle/dill requires for some reason the class to be where it was or accessible upon loading; which defeats the entire purpose of pickling/dilling it in the first place for us.

Any insights in how to get this to work?  I've tried pkl.dump and dumps.

Thanks for any insights!

Comment: why can't you make the code available? pickling is for serializing data, not code.

Comment: The only way I could possibly make the code available is by transferring a .py file across the wire and importing the module and forcing the ML team to adhere to a production training run.  Which is what I'm considering at the moment.  The code changes way too frequently; but it at least adheres to an interface.

Comment: I would like both teams to be able to move at their pace and model updates not require a web tier update.  I would prefer web tier outtages due to updates to be for major release as opposed to model tweaks.  I would also like to change out various models independently of the entire web tier.

Comment: So, you don't have a source versioning system for the models? Just checkout the repository on the server and update whenever necessary. You could even setup commit hooks to do it for you.

Comment: That would require the ML science team to have access to the web teams repo; not sure I like that... I think this may end up boiling down to be solved by process and not code though...

Comment: well I suppose also it would mean that the updates get packed up with our normal web updates via our continuous delivery methodology.  I was hoping to have those two streams independent

Comment: This doesn't answer your original question, but instead of pickling, can you use the TensorFlow saved-model-format (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/saved_model/README.md) to package and distribute the model? (FWIW, this is what Google Cloud ML engine does: https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/how-tos/deploying-models)